# How do I configure mediawiki to show heading numbering/lettering in the document?

Tags: mediawiki

When the table of contents is generated, it numbers sections based upon their heading:

```
1. section 1  
2. section 2  
2.1 section 2.1  
2.2 section 2.2  
3. section 3
```

I would like these section numbers to appear at the paragraph level as well:

```
1. (section 1 header text)
... section 1 content ...

2. (section 2 header text)
... section 2 content ....
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a user-preference to make all headings use outline numbering, but no way to make that a default for all users. Here's a few lines of code which can be added to your LocalSettings.php file which do that.

```
$wgExtensionFunctions[] = 'wfNumberHeadings';
function wfNumberHeadings() {
    global $wgUser;
    $wgUser->setOption('numberheadings', true);
}
```

Comment: It's been 6 years since the answer. Is there a new way how to make the extentions working globally?

Comment: This works great for permanently disabling header numbering on pages (while maintaining TOC numbering).  However the User Preference "Auto number headings" is now useless.  Can we remove that user-pref option somehow?  Or is it possible to just edit all existing and new user's prefs to set `numberheadings = false` but then they can still reenable it if desired?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Auto-number_headings), you can also change in LocalSettings.php to make this behavior the default.

```
$wgDefaultUserOptions['numberheadings'] = 1;
```

Comment: This didn't make any visible difference on my wiki.  Perhaps this only works for users created after you add this line - then their 'default' setting will be to not show numbers - ok if you have a brand new wiki.  Would also need a command to apply the setting to all existing users (eg. via MySQL?).

Answer (score 0):

I found that this extension was the best way to go:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:NumberedHeadings

Also, the OP wants to number your paragraph levels as well - I'd say just make all paragraphs actually SubHeading#5 and use CSS to make it look ho